# Adding types for Global variables defined in Webpack

Tags: node.js, typescript, webpack

I have defined a variable named `__DEV__` in the following manner:

```
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      __DEV__: JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'),
    })
```

How can I add typings for these so that TypeScript can recognize this variable?
I'm using it in the following manner:

```
if (__DEV__) {
 // development only
}
```

Comment: `declare global {
    const __DEV__: "true" | "false"
}`

Comment: @AluanHaddad Where should this be added? In a `.d.ts` file?

Comment: It will work in in a `.d.ts` or `.ts` or a `.tsx`. I usually put this kind of code in a file called `augmentations.d.ts` but that is just a convention.

Comment: works with `tsc`, `ts-node` has a problem with it. Give the following error:
`ReferenceError: __DEV__ is not defined`

Comment: That sounds like a runtime error. If so, I am not surprised. What does the webpack plugin have to do with ts-node? You would need to define `__DEV__` before you use it. In Webpack, that plugin makes it available to code processed by Webpack.

Comment: Yeah got that! Thanks for the help :)